# General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am developing an app with Laravel + MySQL for online exam assessment. A lot of users submit their response at the same time (within the span for few mins) so there is heavy load on the database server.

I am getting several `General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` during many concurrent submissions.

I enabled slow query log and saw following entries in my log

```
update `form_responses` set `photo_url` = 'https://example.com/ae252b371effc7cb11dbcbbb18602026.jpg', `form_responses`.`updated_at` = '2020-09-26 11:39:17' where `id` = 32407;
```

As per my understanding, this is just a simple row update with a primary column being queried (means indexing should work).

But what I can't wrap my head around is - why Innodb is not using row level locking and provide a lock on this particular row. Is there some specific Innodb value I should increase this in case?

Comment: Please consider posting to pastebin.com (and share the url) the last 100 lines of your Slow Query Log and complete TEXT results of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; after one of these events for analysis.

Comment: @VikasSinghai  Please consider posting the information requested Sep 26 at 17:54 and post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE form_responses; for analysis.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB **is** using row level locking.

Problem is, the application or the ORM are using it the wrong way, not giving MySQL sufficient information on what is to be done, resulting in a deadlock.

The **easiest** - not, I hasten to say, the most efficient! - way to overcome this problem is probably to resort to *advisory locking* if you find out that the updates all happen in the same small set of methods.

Note that it is not at all a given that your deadlock is in that table; you should run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to see what the last detected deadlock was. For instance you'll find:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
200915 11:31:03
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 22B8A76B9, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 11161737, OS thread handle 0x7fd06d708700, query id ... UPDATE table SET ... WHERE Dat_UsrId = '11254' && Dat_CreUte='...' && Dat_Tip = 'C'

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 22B8A76B4, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
2616 lock struct(s), heap size 244152, 7262 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 11161676, OS thread handle 0x7fd06ca97700, query id ... UPDATE table SET ... WHERE ...

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 866959 page no 46 n bits 1616 index `NewIndex2` of table `schema`.`table` trx id 22B8A76B4 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 866959 page no 68831 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `schema`.`table` trx id 22B8A76B4 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
```

Notice that here the logical error is in transaction TWO's query. This is a very strong hint:

```
2616 lock struct(s), heap size 244152, 7262 row lock(s)
```

...the WHERE needs to lock 7262 rows (!), which from the application logic's point of view is completely nonsensical (see also [this](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2013/10/31/on-mysql-locks/) for an explanation of "gapping").

Otherwise, you can resort to explicit transactions plus table level locking with `LOCK TABLE form_responses WRITE`.

The most efficient way to do it is to have all involved methods to enter an explicit transaction:

```
SET autocommit = 0;
UPDATE form_responses ... WHERE id = ...;
COMMIT WORK;
```